# ありませんと - possible interpretations

Tags: meaning, expressions

My understanding of ありませんと is that it is an abbreviated form of ありませんと(だめ/いけない/ならない), but the formal ません throws me off. I was under the impression that the formal part should be always the last one, so it should be ないと(だめです/いけません/なりません). Is it possible that abbreviation moves the formality before と? Are the following interpretations possible?

> ... must be
>
> ... must have something

Comment: You will get a better answer (and do so more quickly) if you told us in what context you found ありませんと.

Comment: I heard it over the radio at the end of the sentence.  Unfortunately I did not catch the beginning. Can it be viewed as a general formula: statement + ありませんと?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know the context, and I'm not confident with this answer, but here goes. You may know that ～ないと, ～なくては（なくちゃ）, and ～なければ（なきゃ）are often used as shorthand for ～ないとだめ et cetera. In ありませんと, ～ませんと basically acts as shorthand for ～ないとだめです - being explicitly polite while still cutting off the ending.

Also, you really should know this, but the negative of ある is simply ない, not あらない or anything.

Comment: The argument about ない vs. ならない is valid only in the context of  標準語 (standard Japanese)

Comment: @BouzuHarinezumi ^ では、「あらない」は、どの地域で使われる方言ですか？